# How to find the patient with at least two HbA1c values more than 6.5 at least two years apart using R

Tags: r

Now I have a dataset contains Patient ID, the year of measurement of HbA1c, and the value of HbA1c.

1. I want to find the PATIENT_ID who had at least two measurements of HbA1c >= 6.5 apart at least two years. I would like a dataset with PATIENT_ID and the first time of HbA1c >=6.5 and the value of HbA1c.
2. I want to find the PATIENT_ID and the date and the value of Hba1c, the row at which the last time HbA1c >=6.5 for a patient (mean after which all HbA1c would be >=6.5 for a patient).

Thank you very much.

```
df <- data.frame(PATIENT_ID=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3),
                 TEST_DATE=c(2001,2001,2006,2002,2004,2006,2001,2006),
                 HbA1c=c(6.4,6.5,6.3,6.7,6.1,6.9,6.7,7.0))
```

The expected output:

(1)

```
df <- data.frame(PATIENT_ID=c(2,3),
             TEST_DATE=c(2002,2001),
             HbA1c=c(6.7,6.7))
```

(2)

```
df <- data.frame(PATIENT_ID=c(2,3),
                 TEST_DATE=c(2006,2001),
                 HbA1c=c(6.9,6.7))
```

Comment: Can you show expected output for both of your questions?

Comment: For output (2), should PATIENT_ID=1, TEST_DATE=2001, HbA1c=6.5 be included?

Comment: No. All HbA1c should be >=6.5. For Patient 1, he had a HbA1c of 6.3 in 2006.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  arrange(TEST_DATE) %>%
  filter(HbA1c >= 6.5) %>%
  group_by(PATIENT_ID) %>%
  filter(diff(range(TEST_DATE)) >= 2) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 2 x 3
#   PATIENT_ID TEST_DATE HbA1c
#        <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
# 1          2      2002   6.7
# 2          3      2001   6.7

df %>%
  arrange(TEST_DATE) %>%
  group_by(PATIENT_ID) %>%
  filter(rev(cumall(rev(HbA1c >= 6.5)))) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 2 x 4
# # Groups:   PATIENT_ID [2]
#   PATIENT_ID TEST_DATE HbA1c a    
#        <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>
# 1          2      2006   6.9 TRUE 
# 2          3      2001   6.7 TRUE
```

Comment: If I want to find the Patient with the difference in TEST_DATE between 2 and 4 months (>=2 and <=4). How should I write the codes? Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps replace `diff(range(TEST_DATE)) >= 2` with `between(diff(range(TEST_DATE)), 2, 4)`?

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
```

Answer 1 :

```
df %>%
  group_by(PATIENT_ID) %>%
  slice(if (sum(HbA1c > 6.5) >= 2) which.max(HbA1c > 6.5) else 0)

#  PATIENT_ID TEST_DATE HbA1c
#       <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
#1          2      2002   6.7
#2          3      2001   6.7
```

Answer 2 :

```
df %>%
  group_by(PATIENT_ID) %>%
  mutate(temp = cumsum(HbA1c < 6.5)) %>%
  slice(if(last(HbA1c) >= 6.5) which.max(temp == max(temp) & HbA1c >= 6.5) else 0) %>%
  select(-temp)

#  PATIENT_ID TEST_DATE HbA1c
#       <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
#1          2      2006   6.9
#2          3      2001   6.7
```

Comment: Thank you. Which is the variable for 'TEST_DATE' in the code for question 1?

Comment: @River `TEST_DATE` is from your dataframe `df` itself which you have shared.